# POSIX networking does not activate the cellular radio?

Tags: ios, iphone, sockets, networking

I am reading `Networking Programming Topics:Using Sockets and Socket Streams`, there is a paragraph telling us not to use POSIX socket API on iOS, it says :

> In iOS, POSIX networking is discouraged because it does not activate
>   the cellular radio or on-demand VPN. Thus, as a general rule, you
>   should separate the networking code from any common data processing
>   functionality and rewrite the networking code using higher-level APIs.

As the document states, If I use POSIX socket to do my networking job, so it doesn't activate cellular radio. I have thought that whether it means if my device is not connecting with WIFI, my application will not access to Internet, but I negative it by writing the code below.

In the example, I use only POSIX socket api and connected to google's DNS server, it success when my iPhone is connected with cellular radio (without WIFI).

```
int clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) ;
struct sockaddr_in server_addr ;
bzero(&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) ;
server_addr.sin_port = htons(53) ;
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("8.8.8.8") ;
server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET ;

int i = connect(clientSocket, (const struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) ;
if (i >= 0) {
    NSLog(@"connected") ;
}
close(clientSocket) ;
```

Now my questions are **what it means "activate the cellular radio" and when the system will deactivate the cellular radio** ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: cellular radio is the data communication like 2G, 3G, 4G, etc..

Comment: You should've googled that.

Comment: @rckoenes As the document states, if I use POSIX socket to do my networking job, it won't activate cellular radio, does it means if my device is not connecting with WIFI, my application will not access to internet ?

Comment: Yes that is correct, if I understand that correctly as well\.

Comment: @duci9y I believe it is more convenient to google than asking an question here. I've googled it before asking.

Comment: @rckoenes Updated my question... In fact I have an app which is POSIX socket only(which is supported multiple platform) and it works well.

Comment: It probably means that if for some reason baseband is in some kind of sleep mode that deactivates packet transferring then your POSIX code will not activate it. Don't know whether that could ever happen on a real device that constantly uses the internet. And it probably will be the case only for background applications like VoIP. I don't think foreground application will ever encounter such a problem.

Comment: @creker Do you know in which case cellular radio will deactivated. Even in background, POSIX socket will work, I know it because I have developed an VoIP app.

Comment: I'm only saying that POSIX code may encounter such a problem. Basebands has various sleep modes. Some of them may turn off GPRS part  of the baseband which deals with internet connection. When, why and can it even do that - Qualcomm probably has some internal documents explaining that. iOS devices constantly trying to access the internet. So I don't think there is a big chance you could encounter such a problem with POSIX sockets.

Comment: Found a case when the problem might happen. iPhone 4S, has both cellular and Wi-Fi internet connection. For some reason 4S turns off cellular network adapter while you use Wi-Fi. Only when you turn off Wi-Fi and try to go to the internet the cellular adapter will be up. It happend on my 4S with iOS 6.1.3. Used ifconfig to check network adapters. On iPhone 5 and 5S there is no such problem - both adapters are up at the same time. You can go to the internet using either one.

Comment: @creker Thanks for that. But how did you know that the cellular adapter is turned off ?

Comment: I ran `ifconfig` in Terminal on my jailbroken device. It prints info about all network adapters - flags, IP, mask etc. Cellular adapter, `pdp_ip0`, was down and didn't have IP address. As soon as I went on the internet using safari, `pdp_ip0` was up and printed it's IP address.

Comment: @creker Great! It seems that the iOS system would deactivate the cellular radio under some strategy.

Answer (score 0):

For TCP networking in C, Apple seems to recommend using `CFStream`. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/CommonPitfalls/CommonPitfalls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/CH73-SW4.

Answer (score 0):

[According to "Quinn the Eskimo", an employee from Apple Developer Relations](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/48996):

> Historically the inability of BSD Sockets to activate WWAN was a major
> gotcha, which is why the documentation is littered with references to
> it. On modern systems, however, the WWAN network is pretty much
> pinned up by various system services (most notably push
> notifications).

He says there are other reasons to use `CFSocketStream` or other non-POSIX APIs:

> - BSD Sockets has no connect-by-name mechanism, so you need to manually resolve the name (using `getaddrinfo`) and then connect to each returned address until you find one that works.
> - You must support IPv6, even if the server you’re talking to is IPv4-only (because of DNS64/NAT64).
> - For compatibility with DNS64/NAT64 you should not special case IP addresses.  If you have an IP address, render it as a string and pass it to `getaddrinfo`
> - You should implement Happy Eyeballs.
> - Note I should stress that Happy Eyeballs will not work as well as the built-in connect-by-name mechanism used by Apple’s APIs.  However, it’s probably good enough.
> - For information on what the built-in connect-by-name mechanism does beyond the traditional Happy Eyeballs algorithm, check out [RFC 8305](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8305).
> - You will not be compatible with some features, like VPN On Demand.

> Of these only the last one is Apple specific; everything is just the price you pay for using the ancient BSD Sockets API.